# My Computer is stuck in a loop when I tried to reset it

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I use a lenovo g780 and wanted to reset it completely and keep nothing.  It is however stuck in a loop now.

1. The first screen it shows is the boot up screen while it says please wait.
2. Immediately after, the second screen shows
   System Restore
   You need to sign in as an administrator to continue, but there aren't any administrator accounts on this PC.
   Forgot your password or don't see your account?

^^ This is the only option

3. The final screen shows:
   System Restore
   Forgot your password or don't see your account?
   This list only shows administrator accounts that have previously signed in to this PC, and does not include standard user or domain accounts.  You need to be signed in as an administrator to use some repair and restore tools.  If you don't have a password for any of these accounts, you can restart to try signing in to Windows to manage your user accounts.
   Restart

The only option here is to restart and the whole process starts over again.

How can I end the loop and reboot my computer to factory settings?
Thanks for your time.

Added pictures for reference VV

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te2EH.jpg)
2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmjmQ.jpg)
3. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO7ha.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to keep anything, the solution would be to reformat the disk
and do a clean install.

Create a boot USB as described in the article
[How to Create Bootable USB Flash Drive to Install Windows 10 from](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html).
You will need to do that on another Windows 10 computer, since yours will not boot.

To install Windows, follow the article
[How to Clean Install Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1950-clean-install-windows-10-a.html).

When arriving to the Drive options screen, choose the disk and format it,
so it becomes one Unallocated space.
Choose that Unallocated space for installing Windows.

The above linked articles are very detailed with screenshots.

Comment: Thanks!  It worked!